# Python: Valores NAN al Cargar csv en SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Estoy intentando cargar un csv en `SQL Server`, el csv tiene en algunos campos un espacio en blanco, si borro esos espacios blancos la carga funciona bien con este código:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


# Import CSV

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\user\path\DBM\fichero.csv',sep=";")   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['columna1','columna2','columna3'])
df = df.astype(str)


df['columna1'].str.rstrip()
df['columna2'].str.rstrip()
df['columna3'].str.rstrip()

# Connect to SQL Server


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=server_name;'
                      'Database=Test_DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE _python_test ([columna1] [nvarchar](50),[columna2] [nvarchar](50),[columna3] [nvarchar](50))')

for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Test_DB.dbo._python_test (columna1,columna2,columna3)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.columna1, 
                row.columna2,
                row.columna3
                )
conn.commit()
```

Pero quiero evitar manipular el fichero manualmente antes de cargarlo, sobre todo por automatizar el proceso. Cuando pruebo con este código:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


# Import CSV

data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\user\path\fichero.csv',sep=";")   
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['columna1','columna2','columna3'])
df = df.astype(str)


df['columna1'].str.rstrip()
df['columna2'].str.rstrip()
df['columna3'].str.rstrip()

# Connect to SQL Server


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=server_name;'
                      'Database=Test_DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create Table

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE _python_test ([columna1] [nvarchar](50),[columna2] [nvarchar](50),[columna3] [nvarchar](50))')





for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Test_DB.dbo._python_test (columna1,columna2,columna3)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.columna1, 
                row.columna2,
                row.columna3
                )
conn.commit()
```

Carga los valores de dos de las columnas como `NAN`.

También he probado `replace()` en lugar de `rstrip()` y me da el mismo resultado:

```
# df['Columna1']=df['Columna1'].str.replace(' ', '')
# df['Columna2']=df['Columna2'].str.replace(' ', '')
# df['Columna3']=df['Columna3'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

Parece que espacios la carga funciona bien, pero si intento corregir los espeacios con Python, carga el dato como `NAN` en la tabla SQL.

Ayuda para un novato por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos paso por paso.

### 1. ¿Qué es NaN?

`NaN` significa **Not a Number** es un valor muy conocido en Python sobre todo en librerías de cálculo númerico o manejo de datos, sirve para representar de forma numérica, objetos que no pueden ser representados.

### 2. Cómo solucionar el problema

`NaN` en SQL es interpretado como un string, cuando tu posiblemente quieres que lo ponga como `NULL`, para ello tienes que cambiar los valores `NaN` a `None` que es la "transformación" del `NULL` en Python. Siguiendo tu ejemplo puedes hacer:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace({np.nan:None})
```

Obviamente si no quieres que los lea como `NULL` puedes poner cualquier otro valor.

### 3. Comentarios a tu pregunta

Como has puesto que eres novato te dejo estas anotaciones por si te son de interés

> Pero quiero evitar manipular el fichero manualmente antes de cargarlo, sobre todo por automatizar el proceso.

El limpiado y preprocesado de datos es una parte importante y por tanto debe estar incorporado y automatizado en los scripts que hagamos. Es decir, la limpieza del dato debe ser parte de tu automatización.

Una buena automatización debe tener en cuenta todos los sucesos y los tipos de datos que pueden llegar, para que sean tratados correctamente y que independientemente de la forma en que llegen los datos, el resultado sea el esperado.